# parsing error on guards

Tags: parsing, sorting, haskell, merge

I'm implementing the merge subroutine of merge sort. I'm getting this error message when compiling: parse error on input |

```
merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge xs ys = go xs ys []
    where go xs ys zs =
            |null ys              = zs ++ xs                     
            |null xs              = zs ++ ys                        
            |(head xs) <= head ys = go (tail xs) ys (head xs : zs)  
            |otherwise            = go xs (tail ys) (head ys : zs)
```

can anyone tell me why? Also is there a more succinct way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: You have an extra `=` after `go xs ys zs` - when defining something with guards, the `=` comes only after each guard, as you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix the syntactic error by removing the `=` after `go xs ys zs` - when defining something with guards, the `=` comes only after each guard, as you already have.

Apart from that, your code would be a lot cleaner if you used pattern-matching more. Instead of checking whether a list with `null` and then inspecting the `head` and `tail`, you can use the patterns `[]` to identify empty lists and `(x:xs)` to both identify non-empty lists and to bind the head and tail to the names `x` and `xs`, etc:

```
merge :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
merge xs ys = go xs ys []
    where go xs [] zs          = zs ++ xs
          go [] ys zs          = zs ++ ys
          go (x:xs) (y:ys) zs
              | x <= y         = go xs (y:ys) (x:zs)
              | otherwise      = go (x:xs) ys (y:zs)
```